# Netbeans search in project files stopped woking from one day to another

Tags: java, php, search, netbeans

Just as I say, from one day to another, it stopped.

I can use the "Fing" option on "Projects" window but I get always the same message "No matching files found"

[image: I search for $table_rows that it's at the begining]

I've tried to fix it upating java version from 9 to 17 but it's still failing also I updated Netbeans from 11.3 to 12.4 and I got the same result.

After spent some time on the internet I haven't found any solution yet.

My current SO:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Best regards.

Edit with a new screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your screenshot because the "Scope" value is not fully displayed, and neither is the file name where you expect to find your matching text. Can you set the "scope" to just be the specific project, rather than a single file? What happens in that case? (Also, make sure all changes are saved before searching.)

Comment: Hi @andrewjames this example it's quite simple, I'm searching "$table_rows" in the project files. As you can see, the string is in the top of the script but I only get "No matching files were found" 

It happens with all the projects, it seems that the function it's broken, but I have no clue or log to check it.

Regards.

Comment: The "scope" setting in your screenshot does not appear to be "all projects". I can't see exactly what it is because the text is truncated. You should change it, to be sure.

Comment: I've added a new screenshot, that scopes all open projects. It's not able to find "$GOT" been in the background script.

Comment: Thank you - that is clear! You can try to clear the cache:  Go to Help > About, and note the location of the cache directory. Exit from NetBeans. Delete the Cache directory from your filesystem. Restart NetBeans. Wait for your project to open. Then repeat the search. I don't know if that will help, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames I've done it but it still fails. Could be an error log on netbeans to check it?

Comment: The log file is in the user directory. Go back to Help > About to see the location of your user directory. Then, in that directory, look in the `var` directory and then the `log` directory. The main log file is `messages.log`.

Comment: Update! There is no error message when I try to search something. Stuck again.

Comment: Uninstall and re-install? This is such a fundamental piece of NetBeans functionality, I can't think of any reason why it is not working. Do _any_ searches work? Is it just a specific _type_ of search which is not working?

Comment: That was the most strange thing, I installed the latest version, from 11.XX to 12.something and it didn't work. Also I changed the java version too, but I got the same effect.

I can search in an open document, it works.